# Time Series Forecast as a Probability

Tags: time-series, probability, bayesian

I am looking to create a model that takes in a time series, and outputs the probability that the time series will exceed some threshold over some future time frame (thresholds are pre-determined by me). I would like then to constantly update the model as more data is received so it is constantly updating these probabilities.

For example, I observe the temperature every minute from 2am - 8am, what is the the probability that the temperature in the next 5min exceeds X degrees.

I am familiar with ARIMA models, but my time series tends to exhibit heteroskedasticity so I don't think those techniques are relevant to this situation (correct me if I am wrong). It's almost like I want a bayesian model that works for time series, but I have never come across such a thing.

I see this [similar thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/189332/136472) but it was kind of vague and not helpful.

Any ideas of what kind of models I can look into for this kind of setup?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what kind of time series you have, and what the heteroskedasticity is? ARCH/GARCH expressly model heteroskedasticity, and you can easily extract the probability for the realization to exceed some threshold. Here is a related thread: [Making a time series prediction for events per second based on past data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/217809/1352). Also [Bayesian time series modeling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-series%2bbayesian) is certainly a Thing.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I am looking at financial time series data of prices.

Comment: That is where one would typically use ARCH/GARCH. Any particular reason why these do not work?

Comment: I authored the response to https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/189332/136472 . If you wish to send me your data and also your model and the particular threshold value I will try and help you..

Comment: @IrishStat Thanks for commenting. I cannot share my data, but this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/8y7gvs/d_predicting_probability_distribution_of_value_in/) is very similar to what I am trying to achieve. My data is tick by tick data of major exchanges.

Comment: Then why don't you select and post a time series say with 100 observations and you post a critical value for the next period and I will develop a model automatically and I will post material that details the probability calculation.